# Retrieving related data using edmx and repository pattern

Tags: repository-pattern, edmx

I am writing a simple mvc application with edmx and repository pattern.

I have the following table structure.

```
1) Employee
    ColumnName:Name,ProjectCode
2) Project
    ColumnName:Code,ProjectName
```

There is only data relationship between these two table,no association is defined in database between them.
I have to display projectname in list view of Employee in place of projectcode.  So I have retrieve ProjectName from Project table for every entry of projectcode in Employee.

I have already created a repository class for employee.

What is the best and easiest way implement this requirement? I would prefer not to create a repository for Project entity just for retrieving ProjectName column value for provided code.

Comment: Don't use the repository, use directly EF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Generic Repository pattern` instead of creating each of repository.Using that either way you can query the context and navigation property do the rest of the things for you.
Following links will explain the implementation of generic repository pattern.

- [Here](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/)
- [Here](http://csharppulse.blogspot.com/2013/09/learning-mvc-part-6-generic-repository.html)

Comment: Even better, don't use the Repository at all, instead of making a mess with the generic repository anti pattern.